# Failed to execute goal on project Reports: Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: maven, dependencies, azure-pipelines, cicd

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Reports: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.pcms:Reports:war:1.0.1-RELEASE: Could not find artifact com.pcms:CommonUtils:jar:1.0.1-RELEASE in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
The process '/usr/bin/mvn' failed with exit code 1
Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.

I need to implement CI/CD on Azure portal where I used to build app through azure pipeline but for this particular app getting errors please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.